# How to address binary transfer protocols with multiple "fields" in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: openapi

I have an API endpoint, that requires binary input. I have to document that using the OpenAPI 3.0 specification.

The binary input of that API endpoints expects the following:

| Byte position | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 - 15 | Nonce |
| 16 - EOS | Data (until end of stream) |

Another endpoint would expect the following:

| Byte position | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Action |
| 1 - 8 | Fixed data 1 |
| 9 | Size ("n") of data 2 |
| 10 - 13 | Size ("m") of data 3 |
| 14 - 14+n | Data 2 |
| 15+n - 15+n+m | Data 3 |
| 16+n+m - EOS | Data 4 (until end of stream) |

Is this "documentable" at all with OpenAPI 3.0? I only have found simple "single data" binary upload (e.g. file uploads) and multipart file uploads. However, those does not apply to my scenario because I do not have fields (named or as an array), I have a "raw binary protocol".

Edit: If there is no way to document this, how can I document this within OpenAPI for humans only.

Comment: This is a great question to ask in the OpenAPI repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/discussions. I think (but not sure) that the answer is "this cannot be documented".

Comment: yes it is perfectly well documentable with OpenAPI for human readers. You can describe a request body, a whole endpoint, and the response, and all of them are allowed to contain markdown (and I generally recommend to make use of that). The point is, OpenAPI is for RESTful APIs, so best find a documentation that matches your binary API's philosophy. For streaming, you may want to look into gRPC.